# How to get all forms in a VB.net (VS08) project in an array?

Tags: vb.net

Alright, so I need a method that traverses all the forms inside a VB.net project under Visual Studio 2008, and create an array of type form with references to all the forms inside it, so that the array looks like this (pseudocode)

```
FormsArray() = [Form1, Form2, Form3, Form4]
```

However, I don't have a clue as to how to begin.

Comment: Wait... looking at the answers provided so far, I'm confused about exactly what you're looking for. Do you want the Forms that were defined in the project at design time, or do you want to get the Forms that are defined in the *assembly* at runtime?

Comment: Is this for the program itself, or for a visual studio add-in?

Answer (score 3):

You have to adjust the function to put the result of `msgbox` in a array

```
Public Sub getallforms(ByVal sender As Object)
    Dim Forms As New List(Of Form)()
    Dim formType As Type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form")
    For Each t As Type In sender.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
        If UCase(t.BaseType.ToString) = "SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM" Then
            MsgBox(t.Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

You must call the function from any form in the application like this (`getallforms(me)`)

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you would do this using Reflection, assuming that the class where you placed this code was in the same assembly that you wanted to iterate over. If not, then you'll need to change the Me.GetType().Assembly in the For Each loop into something else to account for loading the assembly in a different manner.

```
Dim Forms As New List(Of Form)()
Dim formType As Type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form")

For Each t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
    If t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Then
        Forms.Add(CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form))
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is what I did to get the list of forms in my vb project, how ever this in not in code but you could write system.io code fragment to do just that.

1. open cmd prompt
2. go to project folder
3. run a dir /s/b *.designer.vb >> list.txt
4. use notepad or sublimetext and edit it to get the list ordered as you like it.

:) hope this helped!

Answer (score 1):

I could not get this version to work:

```
Dim Forms As New List(Of Form)()
Dim formType As Type = Type.GetType("System.Windows.Forms.Form")

For Each t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
    If t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Then
        Forms.Add(CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form))
    End If
Next
```

In VB2010 formType is always Nothing
So I dumped the formType line and simply modified your 'IF' statement to check the BaseType instead. Here is the New Version

```
Dim Forms As New List(Of Form)()
For Each t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
    If t.BaseType.Name = "Form" Then
        Forms.Add(CType(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form))
    End If
Next
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to either write a VS macro or an Addin.

In it, from a DTE or DTE2 instance, you can write:

```
Public Sub GetForms(ByVal host As DTE2)

    Dim project As Project = host.ActiveDocument.ProjectItem.ContainingProject
    For Each ce As CodeElement In project.CodeModel.CodeElements

        If ce.Kind = vsCMElement.vsCMElementClass Then

            Dim cl As CodeClass = CType(ce, CodeClass)
            If cl.IsDerivedFrom("System.Windows.Forms) Then

                'do something 
            End If
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score -1):

2 options

1. I would load the actual project file into a XML reader.  Then iterate all the nodes looking for all Form SubTypes and store the linked files in an array.  If the name of file matches the name of the form class, you can create your FormsArray from that list.  Otherwise you have to load each file and look for the public class definition of the file to get the list.
2. Using Reflection, examine the project using Assembly.GetTypes.  Find all the System.Windows.Forms.Form Types and store them in a list.  Then write out the Type.Name.

Comment: -1: "I would load the actual project file into a XML reader", the proper way would use VSTA, as Timores shows.