# How can I use for each loop with Context Menus?

Tags: vb.net

There is any way to use `For Each` loop with **multiple ContextMenu** controls?
I want to do something like the example bellow...

```
For Each lbl As Label In Me.Controls
    'Some code here...
Next
```

But for ContextMenu controls...

```
For Each cmenu As ContextMenu In ???
```

What should I use in place of `Me.Controls`?

Comment: Context menus don't get added to the form controls, so you have to create a collection of any `ContextMenu` that you need to loop over.

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Are you using the old ContextMenu class or the new ContextMenuStrip class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using the [`ContextMenuStrip`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip(v=vs.110).aspx) class which replaces and adds functionality to the `ContextMenu` control of previous versions, you can use a similar code:

```
For Each x As Object In Me.components.Components
    If TypeOf x Is ContextMenuStrip Then
        MsgBox(CType(x, ContextMenuStrip).Name)
    End If
Next x
```

You need to use [Reflection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/reflection-and-codedom/reflection) in order to find every `ContextMenuStrip` in the collection of open forms owned by the application.

```
For Each frm As Form In My.Application.OpenForms

    For Each fi As System.Reflection.FieldInfo In frm.GetType.GetFields(
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.NonPublic Or _
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.Instance Or _
        System.Reflection.BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly)

        If fi.FieldType Is GetType(ContextMenuStrip) Then
            MsgBox(frm.Name & " - " & TryCast(fi.GetValue(frm), ContextMenuStrip).Name)
        End If

    Next fi

Next frm
```

Comment: No I am using the `MetroContextMenu` from **MetroFramework Modern UI 1.4.0** controls, but your example worked 100%!!! Probably it is composed by a ContextMenuStrip. Thank you very much for your help my friend!!!

Comment: One more question... I am using it into a module for every form of my project, so I have to replace `Me` with something else!!! I tried something like `Form.ActiveForm` or `My.Application.OpenForms` but nothing. Any idea?

Comment: MsgBox doesn't show up when I call the `Sub` that contains the code!!! I am talking about your second example.

Comment: In case I am working with a MetroFramework Form, do you think should I make any changes to `My.Application.OpenForms` part?

Comment: `My.Application.OpenForms` returns a collection of open forms. If you need every forms in a project give a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2359574/how-to-get-all-forms-in-a-vb-net-vs08-project-in-an-array

Comment: Maybe using `MetroFramework` you need to verify if `fi.FieldType` is `MetroContextMenu`, as you stated in comment above.

Comment: You are right at your last comment my friend. In my case, I had to replace every `ContextMenuStrip` with `MetroFramework.Controls.MetroContextMenu`. Thank you again!!!