# how to get list all buttons in all forms of the project

Tags: vb.net

I have the next code to get all forms in the project in vb.net.

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim myAssembly As System.Reflection.Assembly = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()

    Dim types As Type() = myAssembly.GetTypes()
    For Each t As Type In types
        If UCase(t.BaseType.ToString) = "SYSTEM.WINDOWS.FORMS.FORM" Then
            MessageBox.Show(t.Name)
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

how to get a list of all buttons in all project's form?

Comment: What's the goal?  Is this for some sort of source code audit or actually info required at runtime?  If it's a source code audit type thing, you could just parse the source files as text and find instance of button class definitions

Comment: Are there sub-forms? As in, forms within forms (within forms)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dim formType As Type = Me.GetType().BaseType
        Dim forms As List(Of Form) = (From t In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes() Where t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Select DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)).ToList()
        For Each f In forms
            Dim ctrl As Control = f.GetNextControl(Me, True)
            Do Until ctrl Is Nothing
                If TypeOf ctrl Is Button AndAlso ctrl.Name <> "cmdClose" Then
                    ctrl.Enabled = False
                End If
                ctrl = f.GetNextControl(ctrl, True)

                If ctrl Is Nothing Then
                    GoTo Line1
                Else
                    If ctrl.GetType = GetType(Button) Then
                        MsgBox(f.Text & " _ " & ctrl.Name)
                    End If
                End If
Line1:
            Loop
        Next
```

Comment: I think that that is some pretty ordinary code: a completely unnecessary `GoTo`, long-winded boolean determination, etc. Not a good solution IMHO.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how to get every Form in your project: https://stackoverflow.com/a/2364515/1920035

You can use this recursive method to get every control on a Form:

```vb
Private Function GetAllControls(root As Control) As  IEnumerable(Of Control)
    Dim children = root.Controls.OfType(Of Control)().ToList()

    For index = children.Count - 1 To 0 Step -1
        children.AddRange(GetAllControls(children(index)))
    Next

    Return children
End Function
```

Putting it all together, it would look something like this:

```vb
Dim formType As Type = Me.GetType().BaseType
Dim forms As List(Of Form) = (From t In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes() Where t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Select DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)).ToList()
Dim allControls = New List(Of Button)()
For Each f In forms
    allControls.AddRange(GetAllControls(f).OfType(Of Button))
Next
```

Comment: can I get more explanation, I tried that method but I don't know how I can loop on all buttons correctly

Comment: Declaring `formType` gets the base type of a Form (System.Windows.Forms.Form). Declaring `forms` gets every Form in the assembly. Declaring `allControls` declares a new List to store just controls that are Buttons. Inside the For Each, it recursively gets every control using `GetAllControls` but the `OfType` method says that you only want the controls that are Buttons.

Comment: Dim formType As Type = Me.GetType().BaseType
        Dim forms As List(Of Form) = (From t In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes() Where t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Select DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)).ToList()
        Dim allControls = New List(Of Button)()
        For Each f In forms
            allControls.AddRange(GetAllControls(f).OfType(Of Button))
            For i As Integer = 0 To allControls.Count - 1
                MsgBox(allControls(i).Text)
            Next
        Next
I added msgbox to get name of the button , how I can get name the form?

Comment: can you suggest more help please

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking for. The method I provide gives you every button in an application. Do you want something else?

Comment: I want to get the form name with button name (FrmHome_BtnNew),(FrmHome_BtnEdit) etc.

Comment: Dim formType As Type = Me.GetType().BaseType
        Dim forms As List(Of Form) = (From t In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes() Where t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Select DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)).ToList()
        Dim allControls = New List(Of Button)()
        For Each f In forms
            For Each xCtrl As Control In f.Controls.OfType(Of Button)
                MsgBox(xCtrl.Name & " _ " & f.Name)
            Next
        Next

Comment: please see the last comment, I changed the code to get what I want but it doesn't give me any message, why?

Comment: Dim formType As Type = Me.GetType().BaseType
        Dim forms As List(Of Form) = (From t In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes() Where t.IsSubclassOf(formType) = True Select DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)).ToList()
        Dim allControls = New List(Of Button)()
        For Each f In forms

            allControls.AddRange(GetAllControls(f).OfType(Of Button))
            For Each xf In allControls

                MsgBox(xf.Name & " _ " & f.Name)
            Next
        Next
this code gives me some buttons 2 times, why?

Comment: Using my code, after the loop create a new loop to loop over `allControls` and then in the loop call FindForm, something like: ```For Each btn In allControls
    MessageBox.Show($"Form: {btn.FindForm().Name}, Control: {btn.Name}")
Next```

Comment: @David I did that code already but the problem is it gives me also empty values in control  part like (Form: FrmAccounts_Add, Control: "Here it gives me empty value" )

Comment: @Hamada I just tested it without any issue.

Comment: @David maybe the problem is that I have panels and groups inside the forms

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
    Dim allForms As IEnumerable(Of String)
    allForms = From t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                Where t.BaseType Is GetType(Form)
                Select t.Name

    For Each frmName As String In allForms
        MessageBox.Show(frmName)
    Next
```

edit:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Dim allForms As IEnumerable(Of Form)
    'get all forms in project
    allForms = From t As Type In Me.GetType().Assembly.GetTypes()
                Where t.BaseType Is GetType(Form)
                Let f = DirectCast(Activator.CreateInstance(t), Form)
                Select f

    'get all buttons
    Dim allButtons As New List(Of Button)
    For Each f As Form In allForms
        allButtons.AddRange(IterateControls(f))
    Next

    For Each b As Button In allButtons
        Debug.WriteLine(b.Parent.Name)
    Next
End Sub

Private Function IterateControls(ctrl As Control) As List(Of Button)
    Dim rv As New List(Of Button)
    If TypeOf ctrl Is Button Then 'button?
        rv.Add(DirectCast(ctrl, Button)) 'yes
    Else 'no
        For Each c As Control In ctrl.Controls
            rv.AddRange(IterateControls(c))
        Next
    End If
    Return rv
End Function
```

Comment: here you gave a code to get all forms but what I need is to get the buttons in each form

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a short recursive function:

```
Function GetAllButtons(controls As Control.ControlCollection) As List(Of Button)

    Dim buttons As List(Of Button) = New List(Of Button)
    For Each c As Control In controls
        Select Case True
            Case c.Controls.Count > 0
                buttons.AddRange(GetAllButtons(c.Controls))
            Case TypeOf c Is Button
                buttons.Add(DirectCast(c, Button))
        End Select
    Next c
    Return buttons
End Function
```

Call this from the main form code (or wherever you like really):

```
Dim buttons As List(Of Button) = GetAllButtons(Me.Controls)
```